# Not able to understand error message: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString.Create(string)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having the error message:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString.Create(string)' has some invalid arguments

What is wrong in my code? It seems that it does not reach my controller.

I am having the following piece of code in my View:

```
 var list = @MvcHtmlString.Create(myProject.Controllers.TestController.GetList(DateTime.Today));
```

In my controller I have the following piece of code:

```
 public static JsonResult GetList( DateTime date, int ID=0)
    {
        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = myModelModel.UsersList(ID, date),
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
```

UsersList return as follows:

```
> List<DateTime> DatesList = new List<DateTime>(); 
return DatesList.Stringify();
```

Answer (score 1):

GetList() returns `JsonResult` but MvcHtmlString.Create obviousely accepts a `String`

Answer (score 0):

Hi~ If you want to set the string value of JsonResult, you should use like :

```
var list = @MvcHtmlString.Create(myProject.Controllers.TestController.GetList(DateTime.Today).ToString());
```

then the string value of variable"list" might be this:

```
[{id:1,value:abc},{id:2,value:def}]
```

actual string value depends on your datastructure of [myModelModel.GetUnAuthorizedDates]

Comment: the function myModelModel.UsersList(ID, date) returns a list as follows:

Comment: List<DateTime> DatesList = new List<DateTime>();  return DatesList .Stringify();

Comment: Could you tell me what exactly you want to do with Json? get the lsit of DateTime for server-side asynchronous, then show the data on View?  : |